# Is there a way to transform multiple numeric xml values and pass on the sum total?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform some client XML to add the sum of multiple numeric values rather than concatenating them.

The input xml is sometimes malformed so can contain multiple values and the xslt was originally written to expect a single value.

**Client XML**

```xml
<ChargeList>                
<MtxEventCharge>
    <UsageQuantity>1327.0</UsageQuantity>
    <UsageQuantityUnit>100</UsageQuantityUnit>
    <AppliedOfferIndex>1</AppliedOfferIndex>
    <BalanceUpdateIndex>1</BalanceUpdateIndex>
    <UpdateType>2</UpdateType>
    <Amount>9.9525</Amount>
    <ImpactSource>1</ImpactSource>
</MtxEventCharge>
<MtxEventCharge>
    <UsageQuantity>3959.0</UsageQuantity>
    <UsageQuantityUnit>100</UsageQuantityUnit>
    <AppliedOfferIndex>0</AppliedOfferIndex>
    <BalanceUpdateIndex>2</BalanceUpdateIndex>
    <UpdateType>3</UpdateType>
    <Amount>19.795</Amount>
    <ImpactSource>1</ImpactSource>
</MtxEventCharge>
<MtxEventCharge>
    <UsageQuantity>3959.0</UsageQuantity>
    <UsageQuantityUnit>100</UsageQuantityUnit>
    <AppliedOfferIndex>1</AppliedOfferIndex>
    <BalanceUpdateIndex>3</BalanceUpdateIndex>
    <UpdateType>1</UpdateType>
    <Amount>23.754</Amount>
    <ImpactSource>1</ImpactSource>
</MtxEventCharge>
<MtxEventCharge>
    <UsageQuantity>3959.0</UsageQuantity>
    <UsageQuantityUnit>100</UsageQuantityUnit>
    <AppliedOfferIndex>1</AppliedOfferIndex>
    <BalanceUpdateIndex>3</BalanceUpdateIndex>
    <UpdateType>2</UpdateType>
    <Amount>29.6925</Amount>
    <ImpactSource>1</ImpactSource>
</MtxEventCharge>
</ChargeList>
```

**Original xslt**

```xml
<xsl:template name="Charges">

<!-- Get the Charge Events with the relevant Update Type values -->     
<xsl:variable name="AccessCharge" select="./ChargeList/MtxEventCharge[UpdateType=2]" />

<!-- Check if the Access Charge was supplied -->
<xsl:if test="$AccessCharge">
    <!-- Convert and print the amount charged -->
    <xsl:call-template name="MapAmount">
        <xsl:with-param name="amount">
            <xsl:value-of select="$AccessCharge/Amount" />
        </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
```

**Error Message**
FORG0001: Cannot convert string "9.9525 29.6925" to xs:decimal

I have tried to use the sum and tokenize functions to add the values but I cant get this to work

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="sum(for $s in tokenize($AccessCharge/Amount,'\s+')
                  return number($s))" />
```

**Error Message**
A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of tokenize() ("9.9525", "29.6925")

I would like the values 9.9525 29.6925 to be passed through as the combined sum of 39.645

Comment: Please post a reproducible example. You can see something similar working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq7e I suspect you need to change the placement of the `tokenize()` operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `MapAmount` template to

```
<xsl:template name="MapAmount">
    <xsl:param name="amount" />
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(for $s in tokenize($amount,'\s+')
              return number($s)),'#.###')" />
</xsl:template>
```

and remove the leading `.` from your variable

```
<xsl:variable name="AccessCharge" select="/ChargeList/MtxEventCharge[UpdateType=2]" />
```

The output should be:

> 39.645

And if this does not work, make sure that you can use XSLT-2.0, because otherwise your whole code would have to be changed.

Comment: Thanks zx485, this has really helped. Can you clarify what removing the leading `.` actually does please?

Comment: `/` starts the path from the root node, but `./` starts it from the context node. So the former is always the same (same document presumed) and the latter varies.